# Snapshot view is hidden while performing UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to make a simple animated transitioning when pushing a UIViewController, but it seems I am missing something.

I animate a snapshot of a subview from the fromViewController to the toViewController. I am animating snapshot’s frame, but the snapshot is invisible for the whole duration of the animation.

Here is a simple code example. I am trying to animate a single UILabel from the first controller to the second. I specifically want to animate a snapshot taken from the toViewConroller and not from the fromViewController.

```swift
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as! ViewController
    let toVC   = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)   as! SecondViewController

    let container = transitionContext.containerView

    toVC.view.frame = fromVC.view.frame
    container.addSubview(toVC.view)
    toVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    let animatedFromView = fromVC.label!
    let animatedToView = toVC.label!

    let initialFrame = container.convert(animatedFromView.frame,
                                         from: animatedFromView.superview)
    let finalFame = container.convert(animatedToView.frame,
                                      to: animatedToView.superview)

    let snapshot = animatedToView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)!
    snapshot.frame = initialFrame

    container.addSubview(snapshot)

    animatedFromView.alpha = 0
    animatedToView.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2,
                   animations: {
                    snapshot.frame = finalFame

    }) { (_) in
        snapshot.removeFromSuperview()

        fromVC.label.alpha = 1
        toVC.label.alpha = 1

        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    }
}
```

I guess that the snapshot is hidden, because setting the animatedToView’s alpha to 0, however I am not sure how to achieve that animation without setting that.

Comment: I have found snapshotView(...) fails a lot and on certain is version. I almost always drawInContext and add to an Imageview and animate that. It never fails

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code its working fine.I changed a few things like initial frame hardcoded it so i can see the effect and also from viewController alpha.

::::::for presenting view controller

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as! ViewController
    let toVC   = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)   as! SecondViewController

    let container = transitionContext.containerView

    toVC.view.frame = fromVC.view.frame
    container.addSubview(toVC.view)
    toVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    let animatedFromView = fromVC.view!
    let animatedToView = toVC.view!

    let initialFrame = container.convert(CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100),
                                         from: animatedFromView.superview)
    let finalFame = container.convert(animatedToView.frame,
                                      to: animatedToView.superview)

    let snapshot = animatedToView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)!
    snapshot.frame = initialFrame

    container.addSubview(snapshot)

    animatedFromView.alpha = 1
    animatedToView.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2,
                   animations: {
                    snapshot.frame = finalFame

    }) { (_) in
        snapshot.removeFromSuperview()

        fromVC.view.alpha = 1
        toVC.view.alpha = 1

        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    }
}
```

:::::::::::::::::
Use while you are pushing view controller

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.from) else { return }
    guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to) else { return }

    let container = transitionContext.containerView

    container.insertSubview(toView, belowSubview: fromView)

    let animatedFromView = fromView
    let animatedToView = toView

    let initialFrame = container.convert(CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100),
                                         from: animatedFromView.superview)

    let finalFame = container.convert(animatedToView.frame,
                                      to: animatedToView.superview)

    let snapshot = animatedToView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)!
    snapshot.frame = initialFrame

    container.addSubview(snapshot)

    animatedFromView.alpha = 1
    animatedToView.alpha = 1

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2,
                   animations: {
                    snapshot.frame = finalFame

    }) { (_) in
        snapshot.removeFromSuperview()

        //fromVC.view.alpha = 1
        //toVC.view.alpha = 1

        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using this Animator when presenting a UIViewController or when pushing using a UINavigationController? I just tried and it doesn't work when using the animator for push animation, but works all right for presentation animation.

Comment: I am using this for presenting view controller. I will try for UINavigationController and let you know about it.

Comment: check my edited answer,I hope it does the job for you.